# How to control a view with different UITableViewControllers based on parent table selection

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios

I have a Split-View iPad application and I fixed the selections in the popover (RootViewController) to be static, let's say red, yellow, and blue.  When my app starts I have preselected red or the top static text in the cell.  I was able to add UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource with the other templates in DetailViewController.  It's the one with the popover-no-popover default split-view app.

I added the row count and the cell method and voila' my test array populated the detail table.  I want a separate controller (delegate and source) for each selection the user chooses to be driven from didSelectRowAtIndexPath in the RootViewController.

- Should I just add the delegate and datasource templates to the DetailViewController and switch the data based on selections in the RootViewController view?
- Or, would my multiple controller pattern be better design?

I would like some assistance as to how to get the outside controller to have control of the DetailViewController's UITableView.  The DetailViewController is where I instantiate the add button and such to the toolbar.  E.g. when I added the single (Red) test controller to the DetailViewController, any connection to the TableView wasn't seemingly automatic in IB.  You could hover and then it would eventually connect to "View" (ultimately the UITableView).  I've tried everything and I cannot get a simple delegate and datasource controller with a simple NSArray to populate the DetailViewController's table view from RootViewController's didSelectRowAtIndexPath.  This method works because I've debugged and NSLogged the selections.  I'm not creating my ProjectViewController (test or first static text in RootViewController) correctly.  I'll paste some code that I've tried here too.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    // select static row and view controller
    Punch *obj = [self.punchList punchAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"Selected punch object: %@", obj.name);

    ProjectViewController *projectViewController = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];
    [projectViewController tableView:detailViewController.tmpView];
}
```

The ProjectViewController code works if hard-coded in DetailViewController, i.e. the required methods, the count, and the array loaded cells and the   I want this data population in separate controllers because I'm going to use Core-Data in the end.